# Is it possible to run the injected script without reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I did a simple auto form filler, by sending info from a created html to the background and then the content script, so the injected script can change the info on the form.

I know the content script run once the page is load. I want to know if I can run the content script again, without the need of reloading the page.

I got `sendRequest` function in the content script, that I use to make sure it gets the info, only when the page is ready. It then add the info to the form, and wait for me to send it.

In the content script, I added a `onRequest` and it works (it get the info). but, I don't see the changes on the form, unless I am realoding the page.

I want to know if it is possible to do and if it does what subjects should I learn to implent this.

I am new to chrome extentions and I am still learning :)
in 1 of the pages, I use jQuery, so an answer with jQuery would be good too.

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found out that if we create a `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` from **background** we can use **chrome.extestion.onRequest** from **content script** and it will execute every time becuse they both run allmost in the same time.

so i did from **background**:

```
  chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabs[i].id, {...requests u want to send  }, function (response) {

            });

        }
    });
```

from **content script**:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendRespons) {
      //get requested info here
      //call functions.

      sendResponse({}); //send info back to background page.
});
```

Comment: chrome.extension.onRequest in deprecated. please use runtime.onMessage
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#event-onRequest

Answer (score 1):

form's target could be an iframe which would avoid page reload. not sure how useful it'd be.

Comment: i have a few tabs open so i dont think iframe will help me. thx

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to execute a content script again is by using the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method. It receives two arguments. The first argument is the `tabId`, which can be obtained in many ways, such as [one of the `chrome.tabs` events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#global-events). Use `null` to execute the content script in the currently selected tab (caution: this may also be an active dev tools window!).

Examples:

```
// Reloads the current tab
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:'location.reload();'});

// Executes contentscript.js in the current tab
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'contentscript.js'});

// Executes contentscript.js in all frames in the current tab
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'contentscript.js', allFrames: true});

// Receives message from content script, and execute a content script:
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.message === 'load a content script') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.sender.tab.id, {file: 'a_script.js'});
    }
});
     // The previous one is activated from a content script, as follows:
     chrome.extension.sendMessage('load a content script');
```

(`onMessage` and `sendMessage` have to be used instead of `onRequest` and `sendRequest`, since Chrome 20)